# Using scrapy getting crawlspider to work with authenticated (logged in) user session

Tags: html, authentication, screen-scraping, scrapy

Hello how can I get my crawlspider to work, I am able to login but nothing happens I don't really get not scrape. Also I been reading the scrapy doc and i really don't understand the rules to use to scrape. Why is nothing happening after "Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!"

I also had this rule at the end of my else statement but remove it because it wasn't even being called because it was inside my else block. so I moved it at the top of start_request() method but got errors so i removed my rules.

```
 rules = (
                 Rule(extractor,callback='parse_item',follow=True),
                 )
```

my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from linkedconv.items import LinkedconvItem

class LinkedPySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'LinkedPy'
    allowed_domains = ['linkedin.com']
    login_page = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login'
   # start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results?type=companies&keywords=&pplSearchOrigin=GLHD&pageKey=member-home&search=Search#facets=pplSearchOrigin%3DFCTD%26keywords%3D%26search%3DSubmit%26facet_CS%3DC%26facet_I%3D80%26openFacets%3DJO%252CN%252CCS%252CNFR%252CF%252CCCR%252CI"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.linkedin.com/csearch/results"]


    def start_requests(self):
    yield Request(
    url=self.login_page,
    callback=self.login,
    dont_filter=True
    )

  #  def init_request(self):
    #"""This function is called before crawling starts."""
  #      return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
    #"""Generate a login request."""
    return FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'session_key': 'myemail@gmail.com', 'session_password': 'mypassword'},
            callback=self.check_login_response)

    def check_login_response(self, response):
    #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
    if "Sign Out" in response.body:
        self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
        # Now the crawling can begin..
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)

        return 

    else:
        self.log("\n\n\nFailed, Bad times :(\n\n\n")
        # Something went wrong, we couldn't log in, so nothing happens.


    def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n We got data! \n\n\n")
    self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ol[@id=\'result-set\']/li')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = LinkedconvItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('h2/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('h2/a/@href').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

myoutput

```
C:\Users\ye831c\Documents\Big Data\Scrapy\linkedconv>scrapy crawl LinkedPy
2013-07-12 13:39:40-0500 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.16.5 started (bot: linkedconv)
2013-07-12 13:39:40-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetCon
sole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAut
hMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, De
faultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMi
ddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMi
ddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddle
ware
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines:
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider opened
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scra
ped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:602
3
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-07-12 13:39:41-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.linked
in.com/uas/login> (referer: None)
2013-07-12 13:39:42-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.
linkedin.com/nhome/> from <POST https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit>
2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.linkedi
n.com/nhome/> (referer: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login)
2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG:


    Successfully logged in. Let's start crawling!



2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] DEBUG: Hi, this is an item page! http://www.
linkedin.com/nhome/
2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 1670,
     'downloader/request_count': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 65218,
     'downloader/response_count': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 12, 18, 39, 45, 136000),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 11,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 12, 18, 39, 41, 50000)}
2013-07-12 13:39:45-0500 [LinkedPy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now, the crawling ends in `check_login_response()` because Scrapy has not been told to do anything more.

- 1st request to the login page using `start_requests()`: OK
- 2nd request to POST the login information: OK
- which response is parsed with `check_login_response`... and that's it

Indeed `check_login_response()` returns nothing. To keep the crawling going, you need to return `Request` instances (that tell Scrapy what pages to fetch next, see Scrapy documentation on Spiders' callbacks)

So, inside `check_login_response()`, you need to return a `Request` instance to the starting page containing the links you want to crawl next, probably some of the URLs you defined in `start_urls`.

```
    def check_login_response(self, response):
        #"""Check the response returned by a login request to see if we aresuccessfully logged in."""
        if "Sign Out" in response.body:
            self.log("\n\n\nSuccessfully logged in. Let's start crawling!\n\n\n")
            # Now the crawling can begin..
            return Request(url='http://linkedin.com/page/containing/links')
```

By default, if you do not set a callback for your `Request`, the spider calls its `parse()` method (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.parse).

In your case, it will call `CrawlSpider`'s built-in `parse()` method for you automatically, which applies the `Rule`s you have defined to get next pages.

You must define your `CrawlSpider` rules within a `rules` attribute of you spider class, just as you did for `name`, `allowed_domain` etc., at the same level.

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example provides example Rules. The main idea is that you tell the extractor what kind of absolute URL you are interested in within the page, using regular expression(s) in `allow`. If you do not set `allow` in your `SgmlLinkExtractor`, it will match all links.

And each Rule should have a callback to use for these links, in your case `parse_item()`.

Good luck with parsing LinkedIn pages, I think a lot of what's in the pages is generated via  Javascript and may not be inside the HTML content fetched by Scrapy.